# ASync function called even when not used

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, wsdl

I have a very strange problem and I can't explain it.

I'm generating an interface from a wsdl definition, I leave the settings at default so it generates task based methods as well as asynchronous methods. I however only use the task based methods.

This works fine on my machine and on others outside of my client's server. However when I upload to my clients network, my code throws an exception in an asynchronous method that has no reason to be called.

The solution is to wipe the interfaces and ensure the asynchronous methods aren't generated but I'd love to know why they are called. Dead code is dead surely.

Edit #1:

```
request()
{
   requestMsg = initreqMsg();
   try
   {
       responseMsg = GetResp(requestMsg);
   }
   catch(RuntimeError e)
   {
       MessageBox(e.str());
   }
}
```

What seems to be happening is instead of calling GetResp(), the client is calling GetRespASync() and the exception caught in catch(RuntimeError e). This is with oracle RightNow workspace addin and I haven't personally been able to replicate. I first thought they we're running through some automated test suite and triggered the function but no, on my client's machine the code has mutated in a very consistent manner. I'm not ruling out a bug in the plugin architecture, or corruption of the addin but it's happened twice now.

May change my name to "No Clu" ;)

Comment: First read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Need a little bit more than that to answer to be honest. @clu, we have no *clue* what you're talking about yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is reading this and runs into the same, in this case it was another addin on the workspace that was misbehaving, removing it fixed the strange behaviour. Apparently the plugins aren't isolated and can affect each other and/or the client.

Comment: Can you speak a little more about the WSDL?  Are you using a service interface, or did you use something like WSDL.exe?  I had an issue invoking SOAP services from a RightNow AddIn because, I believe, you can use service interface in a DLL file